# DecForms to Java

Tags: java

Can some one help me in approaches / Strategies in converting DecForms to Java? We have about 24 IFDL files which we need to convert to Java based technologies

Answer (score 0):

Porting of Decforms or TDMS to graphical user-interface (GUI) with Cobol, Java or C#

Porting of ACMS to Cobol/Tuxedo, WebLogic, WebSphere, Micro Focus Enterprise Server or .NET platform

Zapforms, developed by Computer Migrations Europe, is an automatic conversion tool for the porting of Decforms or TDMS from OpenVMS to Cobol screen I/O modules (running on Windows, Unix or Linux). Also conversion to Java or C# (or other object oriented GUI) is possible.

If Decforms or TDMS is called from within 3GL programs (e.g. Cobol or Fortran), Zapforms can automatically convert the calls within the 3GL program.

If Decforms or TDMS is called from within ACMS tasks (.TDF), the ACMS transaction monitor must either be converted to another solution (e.g. Tuxedo, WebLogic, WebSphere, Micro Focus Enterprise Server, .NET) or – when the customer needs to keep the business logic on the OpenVMS platform – ACMS can be web-enabled using HP BridgeWorks or TP Web Connector.

Currently, the following automatic conversion solutions are available:

```
Decforms IFDL to Cobol screen I/O, Java or C#
        Conversion of Decforms calls in 3GL programs
TDMS to Cobol screen I/O, Java or C#
        Conversion of TDMS calls in 3GL programs
ACMS definitions (TDF, GDF, ADF, MDF) to Tuxedo transaction monitor with Cobol screen I/O
ACMS definitions to Tuxedo transaction monitor with Java/HTML user-interface
ACMS definitions to J2EE application environment with Java/HTML user-interface
ACMS definitions to Micro Focus Enterprise Server platform
```

In addition, Computer Migrations Europe provides services and expertise for the conversion of the following OpenVMS software products:

```
DEC Cobol to a new Cobol platform (e.g. Micro Focus Cobol, AcuCobol, NetCobol), including OpenVMS system calls and libraries
Oracle Rdb (including RDO / SQLMOD) to Oracle 11g RDBMS
Oracle DBMS Codasyl (including DML) to Oracle 11g RDBMS
DCL command language to Unix shell script (or Windows CMD command)
```